# The code I use to make a UIImageView AspectFit and anti-aliased isn't working on tvOS. Why?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

Here's my code. I use this in iOS projects and it works fine on a UITableView, but for some reason the `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and `setminificationfilter:kCAFilterTrilinear` parts of the code don't seem to be working.

Am I doing something wrong with tvOS? Or is this a possible bug? Can someone confirm they are seeing this same issue or not? Thanks.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Movie *movie = [self.filteredmovies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Set the item image
    __weak UIImageView *anImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    anImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [anImageView.layer setMinificationFilter:kCAFilterTrilinear];
    [anImageView sd_setImageWithURL:movie.coverURL
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading"]
                         options:SDWebImageHighPriority | SDWebImageRetryFailed
                       completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
     {
         if (image == nil || error) {
             [anImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image_Not_Found"]];
         }
     }];

    return cell;
}
```